# Vmware guest O windows 8red color become blue

Tags: 12.04, windows-8, vmware, colors, hosts

I am running VMware worktstaion 10, on Ubuntu 12.04.5, having windows 8 as guest OS.
Very think seem fine expect loss red color, it became blue.

Vmtools were re-install, VM->Setting->DISPLAY, Accelerate 3 Ds graphic were uncheck.

Please help, thanks

Sorry forgot to add image, notice the firefox icon, and sunflower became blue.

[image: firefox icon and sunflower became blue]

Update on 31-Oct-2014

On my machine I have a dual, Ubuntu and Centos. The same vmware, running on Centos Host where were no issue. However, above problem happen on Ubuntu  Host.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on your exact problem - if you could upload a screenshot or reword your question it would help.

Comment: Hi Arnon, 
please original message. Added image.

Comment: Looks like the Inverted Colours accessibility feature is turned on in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Inverted Colors has somehow turned itself on in your Windows 8 guest. Try this to see if you can turn it back off:

1. Press WinKey+F to open the search tool and then type in "Magnifier"
2. Click on "Magnifier" in the search list (not "install magnifier" or something)

   [image: magnifier search]
3. Once Magnifier opens, the screen may, as you might expect, magnify where your pointer is. Ignore this (or hit the minus button until the screen goes back to 100%) and locate the gear icon in the Magnifier window.

   [image: magnifier window]
4. Uncheck "Turn on color inversion" and click "OK".

   [image: magnifier options]
5. Hopefully, this will fix the color issue.

Comment: Hi

Thanks for the detail instruction. However, it was already uncheck.

On my machine I have a dual, Ubuntu and Centos.
The same vmware, running on Centos Host where were no issue.
However, on Ubuntu ithappen.

Comment: @user1121055 - do the colors invert in Windows 8 only, or does the entire Ubuntu system invert as well? You may have the virtual machine set to use more colors than the host system supports.